# Can grep in vim be made to be conditionally case sensitive?

Tags: vim, grep

When I do a in-document search with `/` or `?` it only performs a case sensitive search when a capital letter appears in the search pattern because of the combination of the `ignorecase` and `smartcase` settings. Is there a way to mimic this behavior with the `:grep` command without needing to manually add the `-i` setting manually every time?

Comment: I doubt it, since [the `:grep` command uses the external `grep` tool](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Find_in_files_within_Vim), and AFAIK the `grep` tool itself doesn't have such a feature.

Comment: That doesn't preclude the possibility of a fancy vimscript solution that does something to check the argument and determine the case of it, but I don't know if it's possible or how to do that

Comment: Since this might be useful outside of Vim as well, a better solution might be to (1) make a bash (or zsh or whatever) function that accomplishes this, (2) use the `shellcmdflag` option to load the function (I'm not really sure how to do this but I'm pretty sure that's what the option is for), and (3) call that function instead of basic `grep`. (Or you could just alias `grep` to your new function that calls `\grep`.) If you do end up doing this, let me know--I'd be interested in adding it to my personal setup, but it's not a high enough priority for me at the moment.

Comment: I would suggest you to check out [`ag`](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher), which is a super-fast and more convenient to use replacement for `grep`. It has the feature you want among many others. Of course, there is a [plugin](https://github.com/vim-scripts/ag.vim) for smooth integration with Vim.

Answer (score 7):

You may be interested in looking at `:vimgrep` which can use Vim's regular expressions for pattern matching.  This includes honoring `'ignorecase'` and its related options, unless you explicitly state otherwise. Specifically, if a "`\c`" appears in a pattern it makes the pattern ignore case, and "`\C`" forces case matching. Look at:

```
:help :vimgrep
:help /\c
```

(Yes, the forward- and back-slash are meant to be part of the :help command.)